# Mariadb High CPU Usage %400 After Update 5.5 to 10.2

Tags: mysql, mariadb

My database normal usage is average at 50% but after update MariaDB 5.5 to 10.2, It's getting high usage of 400%. I can't understand how to figure it out.

My server :

- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1231 v3
- 32 GB DDR3 Ram
- List item
- Centos 7 Vestacp

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 1370 mysql     20   0 4976292   1.3g  13432 S 412.5  4.1 148:20.00 mysqld
```

/etc/my.cnf :

```
[client]
#password   = your_password
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

log-bin=mysql-bin
binlog_format=mixed

server-id   = 1

#master-host     =   <hostname>
#master-user     =   <username>
#master-password =   <password>
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>

#log-bin=mysql-bin

#innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
#innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
#innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql
# You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
# of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
# Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
#innodb_log_file_size = 5M
#innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
#innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
#innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
#safe-updates

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 20M
sort_buffer_size = 20M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

How Can I do this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you complete the graceful shutdown of 5.5 before beginning upgrade to 10.2?

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Yes, I've completely shutdown 5.5 and then upgrade but there's was some ddos problems with server maybe due to that I've faced that issue. I just destroyed server and re-setup new one. Thanks for help

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If still high CPU in a few days, please provide data requested a few hours ago - after 24 hours of uptime.